# Cross-platform form functionality for mobile app

Tags: android, ios, forms

I'm not asking for a heated debate on what is the best approach, as I know this would be against StackOverflow rules.

I am building an app natively in Android and iOS and am wondering what are some good ways to set up a form in the app so comments can be made and I can see them, i.e - a feedback form.

No one else needs to see them so I was wondering if there was some method of doing this with Google Forms, or some other alternative.

I know I could just save the comments to a server/database but that's a lot of effort really.

I considered sending the comment/feedback to my email but apparently there are problems with this in iOS development due to spam issues or something.

What are simple ways to go about this, I would like a few options and I can then research some more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple but lengthy steps:

1.Create a form in UI of respective technologies, ie in android java+xml. I don't know about ios much.

2.Send form's parameters just like html form, from client to server. Now you will be sending parameters from app.

3.Handle parameters on server, use phpmailer library for SMTP email. Its fast and your mail would not appear in spam folder.

cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't got a server atm and have very little experience working with one, hence the desire to use google spreadsheets/email. What free server should I set up?

Comment: If you are testing only, you can use your computer as a local server. I recommend to use xampp server.  It includes all sources php, mysql, apache you need.

Comment: I will be releasing the app soon, just as a feedback form, and so I suppose I will need a server running 24/7 to pick up this data. Is there an equivalent to xampp, just online. I am trying to use db4free but I am very new to this stuff so it's taking me a while even figuring out how to connect to the server.

Comment: You have to purchase a domain and hosting. Then only its available round the clock. Suppose your server is sending data in some time interval. Then you have to use GCM API. If not, then use normal web services to send and retrieve data.